# Responsive dimensions with em

Tags: html, css

Today an idea came up and I want to know other peoples opinions before starting to using it. What are the pros and cons for using `em` for almost all properties (`paddings`, `font-size`, `width` , `height` ... ) and controlling them on a block level by setting a font size on their closest parent ? I attached an example below . Thanks.

```css
.steps {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

.steps__item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 6.375em;
  min-width: 8.4375em;
  margin: 0.375em 1.4375em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}
.steps__item--selected {
  border-color: #70b631;
}
.steps__item:hover {
  border-color: #70b631;
}
.steps__wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  
}

.steps__wrapper img {
    width:3.75em;
    }

.steps__description {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8125em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0.625em 0.625em 0 0.625em;
}
```

```html
<section class="steps">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="steps__item steps__item--selected ">
    <div class="steps__wrapper">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x45/ad6bad/fff&text=+" alt="">
      <span class="steps__description">1. Produkt hinzufügen</span>
    </div>
    <!-- end steps__wrapper -->
  </a>
  <!-- end steps__item -->

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="steps__item ">
    <div class="steps__wrapper">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x45/ad6bad/fff&text=+" alt="tshirt image">
      <span class="steps__description">2. Druck hinzufügen</span>
    </div>
    <!-- end steps__wrapper -->
  </a>
  <!-- end steps__item -->

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="steps__item">
    <div class="steps__wrapper">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/60x45/ad6bad/fff&text=+" alt="email icon">
      <span class="steps__description">3. Gratis Angebot direkt erhalten</span>
    </div>
    <!-- end steps__wrapper -->
  </a>
  <!-- end steps__item -->
</section>
<!-- end steps -->
```

Comment: That is, again, completely misunderstanding how you should use this to create responsiveness. You use 'em' on **everything**, so that the user decides (either via his browser's default settings, or via specific user-settings in the OS) how things will look. There is never a reason to specify a set font-height in `px`.

Comment: If I don't specify a font size on their parent I can't control the blocks individually. Maybe the questions title is a bit wrong .The idea is to make it easier for me to create a responsive website just by changing the font-size in a specific block in a media query.

Comment: That's why you set the font-size on html/body to something like ` font:normal 100%/150% arial,helvetica,sans-serif;`and base off of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the absolute wrong approach for the choice of a unit. Each unit is made for a certain reason: `em/rem` are dependent on the users preferences, `vh/vw` are relative to the viewport size and so forth. Unifying the used unit makes no sense, because you should choose the most appropriate unit for the setting at hand. So it is a good idea to use `em/rem` for font sizes, but it is not for setting up a container which should be two thirds as wide as its parent. Therefore percentages are do just fine. Responsive design is not made of a certain unit, it is made of design at first and a good concept about how things should be on different sizes. While turning that into reality, you have to decide which unit to use, there is no »one for all truth«.

**UPDATE**

It is probably worth mentioning how I came to this is: I once, when I had discovered `rem` first, started out with a sass function to convert each and everything to `rem`, so I had a `px2em($px)` method and converted every possible value using this. Since there wasn't to much requirements which should have been solved using percentages the whole thing grew fine. But I came over several issues, which made it unnecessary complicated, even useless. One major issue was connected to rounding issues when it came to hairline borders: Assuming that `1em` equals `16px` (if the user hasn't changed this), a border with width of `1px` becomes `0,0625rem` which in turn resulted in varying rendered widths between browsers, switching back to `px` just solved that. In conclusion I gained a layout that was bound to `rem`, what is a fixed unit with respect to a certain base, so changing the base resulted in nothing else than scaling. After making all the detours I ended up with a non responsive page, which could be scaled by changing the default font size, instead of just using `ctrl+`, or its touch gesture counterpart.

In a nutshell: Units are tools in your toolbox and rejecting a certain tool, or favouring one over the other, is as helpful as using a hammer on screws. Even if that is possible, it just makes more sense to use a screwdriver if available.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely use `em` for all sizes to have a fully responsive design.

Of course there may be some exceptions where you need to have a fixed pixel or percentage size, so leave yourself some space to be flexible.

Don't forget there is also the `rem` unit, which bases off of the default root font-size on the page (usually 16px by default), instead of the parent element. You sometimes want to use that when you have nested blocks--the font size can quickly get away from you and get really large or really small.